# How to access the iframe by XPath for Web scraping using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I only find this possible xPath, because the IDs change when refreshing the page.

It is body that gets an error when executing the code:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/body"/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe
```

Iframe image:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the question ? were you not able to switch to iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this snipet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/scroll')
shop_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='thumbnail']")
```

or this snipet:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
shop_elems[0].get_element(By.XPATH, <XPath Query Here>)
shop_elems[0].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a")
```

for more refernce you can visit here:https://towardsdatascience.com/xpath-for-python-89f4423415e0

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://webapp']")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://webapp')]")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```